# Read int & char array in one scanf

Tags: c

Is it possible to read a character and an integer in one time?
Like this:

```
char name[32];
int age;

printf("Give name and age: ");
scanf("%s%d%*c", name, &age);
```

It blocks all the time.

Comment: It's just not working :D (sorry for the bad English)

Comment: What's the exact input? Is the name made up of sevelar words ("Alice Watson")? The `%d` format may "block" if the found input doesn't translate to a decimal value.

Comment: I've just tested it and it works for me.

Comment: What is your input? Why not skip the newline (which I assume is what you want to remove with the `"%*c"` sequence) by telling the *next* `scanf` to skip leading whitespace (which is done automatically for just about all formats anyway). You might want to read e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: @rodrigo It depends on the input. Try a string with a whitespace in it.

Comment: @A.Abramov Yeah, well, it does not parse the integer, but it returns an error and does not block. That is still working for me.

Comment: @rodrigo OP has poor english, by blocking he meant an error as specified by his comment :)

Comment: "It's not working" is a very bad problem description, can you please be more verbose? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And include (in the question) the actual input you enter, plus telling us what `scanf` returns (if it does return), actual and expected output, and just about as much details as you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED:** You only accept input but not printing any thing. See the below code ( **working and tested** )

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
char name[32];
int age;

printf("Give name and age: ");
scanf("%31s%d", name, &age);

printf("Your name is %s and age is %d",name,age);
}
```

> **intput**: Shaz 30
>
> **Output** : Your name is Shaz and age is 30

Answer (score 2):

```
char name[32];
int age;

printf("Give name and age: ");
scanf("%31s%d", name, &age);
```

If the input `string` is longer than 31 characters, the value read for `age` will be affected, this is where `fgets` comes in handy.

Do not read both the name and age on the same line input. Read the name first to force the user to enter a new line so you can handle the entire line as the input name.

Read [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets)

Comment: Neat answer, plused; one question - why 31?

Comment: @A.Abramov last character must be null to have a valid `C` string

Answer (score 2):

It is one of the method

**CODE**

```
#include<stdio.h>
char name[32],age;
int main()
{

printf("Enter name and age: ");
scanf("%s%d", name, &age);
printf("\nNAME : %s  AGE : %d",name,age);
}
```

[OUTPUT Refer under the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjpbH.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code, there is no error. Maybe you should only add `printf()` to print the answer.You will find you can get the same answer with what you have printed.

**EDIT:** If input is `Colin 23`(the space is necessary), you should use `printf("name is %31s, age is %d", name, age)`. Then you will get output `Colin 23`.

Comment: Try inserting input which contains a space.

Comment: @A.Abramov, yeah, the space is necessary. I have added the example.

Comment: Your edit makes your solution look very similar to Olayinka's to me :/

Answer (score -3):

You can do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[32];
    int age;

    printf("Give name and age: ");
    scanf("%s%d", name, &age);
    printf("%s\n",name);
    printf("%d",age);
}
```

Comment: Why the `&` before the name? It won't work, runtime error.

Comment: It is works.. execute the code. & means we are passing the address.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403154/when-should-i-use-ampersand-with-scanf

Comment: "name" itself represents the address.

Comment: ... since it's an array, `name` is an implicit `&name[0]`

Comment: I was unknown to this fact.. Sry and thnx.. but &name also gives the same result, rite??

Comment: @AniketAmrutkar No, that's not right. You're parsing the address of the string. It's meaningless. Test before you answer.