# Repeating a task/block of code X times (introduced by user)

Tags: c

I recently started coding in c. I was wondering how you can repeat/loop a task as many times as the user wants (by input).

```
int a,i;

scanf("%d", a);
for(i=0; i<a; i++){...}
```

This is the code I came up with, but it doesn't work. It's an infinite loop.

Comment: Read the documentation carefully. `scanf("%d", a);` ---> `scanf("%d", &a);`

Comment: What is a "structure" that you want repeat?

Comment: try to print a to check if the user input really got there... if not, check your scanf carefully...

Comment: Enable all warnings & debug info in your compiler (so with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`....), you should get a warning.

Comment: by structure do you mean a code, function or an actual C structure ?

Comment: Apart from the `scanf` issue mentioned int previous comments, there may be other problems in the `{...}` part. Please edit the question and show your actual code.

Comment: its better to initialize the local variables to zero or some value instead of just define. If you do `int a=0` you won't see any output from `for loop` and second you need to follow `scanf` format properly use `man scanf` in linux system or google

Comment: @ThiruShetty If `a` is initialized to zero, the call to `scanf` will most likely segfault.

Comment: @MichaelWalz i don't know to which compiler you referring, but it works with gcc no segment fault.

Comment: @ThiruShetty [On ideone](http://ideone.com/12uJe5) I get a runtime error.

Comment: @MichaelWalz you will get runtime error if you do either of this 
`int a=0;` or `int a;`
`scanf("%d",a);` because `scanf` expects variable reference and not direct address

Comment: @ThiruShetty that's exactly the point. But _`scanf` expects variable reference and not direct address_ is not quite correct: _`scanf` expects the **address** of the variable and not the **value** of the variable_.

Comment: @MichaelWalz thanks for correcting me, you are correct, `scanf` doesn't expect value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a & to scan into.

```
int a,i;

scanf("%d", &a);
for(i=0; i<a; i++){...}
```

Read a bit more about scanning integers here.

[How to scanf only integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583717/how-to-scanf-only-integer)

Answer (score 0):

Change `scanf("%d", a)` to `scanf("%d", &a)`

The code didn't work for you because you failed to store the value entered by the user.
Before modifying your code as my suggestion try to print the value of `a` in your code, you'll get it, why it's not working..

Comment: Actually, it is **not** an infinite loop - just one running a *very* long time (assuming i is not modified any more within the loop body...).

Comment: you can't predict the value of `i` since compiler assigns garbage to it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in line:

```
scanf("%d", a);
```

You have to use:

```
scanf("%d", &a);
```

`&` sign represents address, you want to store input value on the address of variable `a`.

Read more about ampersand here:
[When should I use ampersand with scanf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403154/when-should-i-use-ampersand-with-scanf)