# Why do we not specify '&' symbol in scanf while scanning a string input in c language?

Tags: c

Normally when we scan int or float or double input we use '&' symbol before the variable but why not in the case of string

Comment: Because a string decays to pointer when passed as a function argument.

Comment: Have you learned about pointers yet? Even the best of books will only present `scanf` with ampersands and say "trust me until later".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18403229/1201599 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403154/when-should-i-use-ampersand-with-scanf/18403229#18403229

Answer (score 1):

When scanning a string, the `%s` format specifier expects an argument of type `char *`.  It is used like this:

```
char str[100];
scanf("%99s", str);
```

We don't need to use `&` here because `str`, when used in a expression *decays* to a pointer to its first element and has type `char *`.  So there's no need to take the address since you already have a `char *.

If you're using dynamically allocated memory:

```
char *str = malloc(100);
scanf("%99s", str);
```

You explicitly have a `char *` already, so again no need to take the address.  If you did, you'd get the address of the pointer variable instead of the address of the allocated memory.  [Bad things will happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if you do this.

Answer (score 0):

It is because in this case array decays to the pointer and this pointer referencing the first char element of this array. So no `&` is needed

```
char str[LEN];
```

`scanf("%s", str)` is equivalent to `scanf("%s", &str[0])`