# What is wrong with using %var after format specifier in a scanf call?

Tags: c

```
main ()
{
int a,b,toplam;
float ort;

printif("iki sayi girin :");
scanf("%d,%d",%a,%b);
toplam=a+b;
ort=toplam/2;
printif("Ortalama= %f olarak hesaplandı.",ort);
}
```

error: expected expression before '%' token scanf("%d,%d",%a,%b);
What was my mistake?

Comment: Change `%a, %b` to `&a, &b` and it is `printf` not `printif`

Comment: @OriDavid That is broken code there in your comment. Would work for printf, but is scanf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Your `scanf` statement should be (using the `&` prefix "address-of" operator):

```
 scanf("%d,%d",&a,&b);
```

and your code is incomplete, since [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) can fail. You should read its documentation.

Consider coding a test against such failure using:

```
if (scanf("%d,%d", &a, &b) < 2) {
   perror("scanf failure");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Read also the documentation of your C compiler, e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), and of your debugger, e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). You could compile your code [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to get all warnings and debug information, and later use `gdb` to debug your executable and understand its runtime behavior.

Your code is missing a `#include <stdio.h>` before your `main`.

The `printif` is wrong. You want to use [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) (and read its documentation).

Consider studying for inspiration the source code of some *existing* [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), such as [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/).

Answer (score 2):

Replace `scanf("%d,%d",%a,%b);` with `scanf("%d,%d",&a,&b);`

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403154/when-should-i-use-ampersand-with-scanf) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the '%' before a and b with '&'.

Also you need to use printf not printif.

```c
int a,b,toplam;
    float ort;
    
    printf("iki sayi girin :");
    scanf("%d,%d",&a,&b);
    toplam=a+b;
    ort=toplam/2;
    printf("Ortalama= %f olarak hesaplandı.",ort);


    return 0;
```