# calling scanf inside do while loop is breaking the loop

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf, c89

I have a `do while` loop. When I run it without `scanf()`, it runs properly. But if I enter a `scanf()` it **breaks** the loop! Why???

The code:

> With `scanf()`

```c
void main(){
    int num = prng() % 100, guessed, guesses = 0;
    bool  win = false;
    printf("The Game Begins. You Have To Guess A Number\n");
    do{ //A do while loop untill the user guesses the correct number
        printf("Guess a number\n");
        scanf("%d", guessed);
        guesses++;
    }while (!check(guessed, num));
    printf("Yayy!!! You won the game in %d guesses!!", guesses); //Message after guessing the correct number
    return;
}
```

*This breaks the loop instantly:*

```
> .\a.exe
The Game Begins. You Have To Guess A Number
Guess a number
5
>
```

> But when I run it without the `scanf()`

```c
void main(){
    int num = prng() % 100, guessed, guesses = 0;
    bool  win = false;
    printf("The Game Begins. You Have To Guess A Number\n");
    do{ //A do while loop untill the user guesses the correct number
        printf("Guess a number\n");
        guessed = num;
        // scanf("%d", guessed);
        guesses++;
    }while (!check(guessed, num));
    printf("Yayy!!! You won the game in %d guesses!!", guesses); //Message after guessing the correct number
    return;
}
```

*It works fine!!*

```
> .\a.exe
The Game Begins. You Have To Guess A Number
Guess a number
Hurrayyy!!!! You got the number!!!!!!!!!Yayy!!! You won the game in 1 guesses!!
>
```

Can you explain what is the actual problem?

Comment: If at all possible, use a modern C compiler!  Mine says`warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int'`, which is your main problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `&` in front of `guessed` variable within the `scanf` function.

`scanf("%d", &guessed);`

An explanation of how `scanf` works can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18403772/15497831).